# OAuth2 Client Authentication Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement an Oauth2.0 Authorization server in `Spring`.

I've been able to retrieve an authorization_code for a user via:
`/oauth/authorize`

but when I take that code and try to redeem an oauth token for it at:
`/oauth/token`
I get an **Error 401: "Bad credentials"**

The url that I use to retrieve the authorization_code is:

```
http://localhost:8084/Oauth/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=tonr&redirect_uri=www
```

and the curl command I use to attempt to grab the token is:

```
curl --user tonr:secret --data "grant_type=authorization_code&code=1pzAm1&redirect_uri=www" http://localhost:8084/Oauth/oauth/token
```

I'm not sure if I have something misconfigured, or if I'm just misunderstanding how Oauth2 is supposed to work. any ideas?

here is my **security.xml:**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="tonr" resource-ids="sparklr" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,implicit"
                      authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" scope="read,write" secret="secret" />
    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <beans:property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                                user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans:beans>
```

and here is my **web.xml**:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Oauth</display-name>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- this mapping is added so that view requests are not defaulted to the app-servlet declared above /\ -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- security stuff-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It turns out that the spring app only had 2 viable users:

```
<user-service>
    <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</user-service>
```

My tonr client was not in this user-service, so spring kept rejecting it.
I just needed to add the client list to a `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService`:

```
<beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>
```

and then add that UserDetailsService implementation to the `<authentication-manager/>` bean:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>
```